# Podcatcher for home server and desktop PC (frontend/backend)

Tags: multimedia, podcast, home-server

I've got a home server that is always on and online but hasn't got a display. What I'd like to do is the following: The server checks my podcast subscriptions and downloads them in the background. When I switch on my desktop PC and open the podcatcher application, the files are already download and I can start listening or syncing right away.

Do you know a podcatcher that is split up like that in frontend and backend?

Answer (score 1):

I use `cron` and`hpodder` (available from Software Center) to update my subscriptions and download my podcasts at night. You could do that, and open your application and point it at the downloaded files.

Comment: Which application do you mean when you say "open your application and point it at the downloaded files"?

Comment: I have my `hpodder` `cron` job download the podcasts to `$HOME/podcasts/<Podcast title>/`, the do some script manipulation to create copies in `$HOME/podcasts/YYYY-Mmm-Dd/`. Then, if my Sony Walkman is connected, uses `rsync` to copy `$HOME/podcasts/2*` to the player. You could use `hpodder`, and `cron` to keep your podcasts up-to-date, and, for example, one of the packages listed by `apt-cache search podcast` to listen and sync..